# Codeigniter summernote fail result

Tags: codeigniter, summernote

I am using the codeigniter framework with the summernote editor.

If I use a single page in php post without the framework, the result is just like this:

```
<span style="font-weight: bold;">asdasdasd</span>
```

But if I use post in codeigniter the result is different, like this:

```
<span  bold;">asdasdasd</span>
```

`style='font-weight: '` is missing..

Why did it happen, and what is the solution?
Thank you for helping.

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: the code just like in [summernote gist](https://gist.github.com/soomtong/6635053), but i use it in codeigniter page..

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer...

in codeigniter don't use :

```
$_POST['content'] OR $_GET['content']
```

but use :

```
$_REQUEST['content']
```

PROBLEM SOLVED!

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a xss filter problem, try to disable or get the value to false.

```
$content = $this->input->post('content', FALSE);
```

I've edited with original summernote example:

```
<div class="span12">
        <h2>POST DATA</h2>
        <pre>
        <?php print_r($this->input->post(NULL, FALSE)); ?>
        </pre>
        <pre>
        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('content', FALSE)); ?>
        </pre>
    </div>
```